# Mongoose how to do multiple updates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having a tough time coming up with a solution to update multiple documents with different values.

I have an app that makes sales for every sold item I want to reduce the quantity in my database by one.

```
var soldItems = 
[

    {
        "_id": "1"
        "name": "Foo",
        "price": 1.09
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "name": "Bar",
        "price": 2.00
    }

]

var ids = [];

soldItems.forEach(function(item){

   ids.push(item._id);

});
```

I'm collecting all the ids in my soldItems array of objects.

Now I want to know how many items quantity I have in the database and then reduce the number quantity by one.

```
ModelItem.find({_id: {$in: ids}}, function(err, docs){
    if(err) throw err;

    docs.forEach(function(doc){

        soldItems.forEach(function(item){

            if(doc._id === item._id){
                doc.quantity += -1;
            }

        });            

    });

    Item.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, {$set: docs }, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;


    });

});
```

Obviously this is wrong because $set is passing in array instead of an object.

I want to know how can I reduce the quantity by one for each item in my database, but I the same time I don't want to go below 0 items in the database.

I'm sure im looking at this from the wrong angle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$inc` operator instead, and the `multi` options:

```
Item.update({_id: {$in: ids}, quantity: {$gt: 0}}, // selection
            {$inc: {quantity: -1}}, // modifications
            {multi: true}); //options
```

Comment: That way works, but for some reason if I select the same id 5 times. it would only reduce the quantity one time per unique id. this is my code I modify it so I no longer need to have the find.  Item.update({_id: {$in: ids}, quantity: {$ne: 0}}, {$inc: {quantity: -1}}, {multi: true});

Comment: That's because even if the `ids` array contains the same id multiple times, the selection query only returns 1 document, not 5 times the same document. Call that line as many times as you want, or change the increment.